# Windows10 - Change SIM PIN with script

Tags: windows-10, mobile-broadband-api

I need to configure about 200 tablet pc (Windows 10, anniversary version).
On each, I must change SIM PIN and disable prompt for it.

I'm able to start cellular settings with `ms-settings:network-cellular` but cannot access the `Advanced options` tab.

Is there any way to do it ?

I tried to make an `AutoIt` script, but sometimes i get two buttons, where other times I get only one, making my script useless.

Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Edit :

Adding images for better understanding :

With `ms-settings:network-cellular` i'm able to show this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNOAB.jpg and I want to access "Options avancées" directly but i can't find anything to do that.

Next screen is https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xVuy.jpg this is the one I use to modify SIM PIN.

Comment: We cannot help you with your script until you've posted it, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47473426/edit) adding the `c#`, `powershell`, `batch-file` and `autoit` code you've tried, what you intended it to do and a full explanation on how each fails to meet that intention.

Comment: I probably miss my tags sorry, because it's not a problem with scripts (i only make one on AutoIt), but i'm looking for a solution to automate the change of the SIM PIN. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Pitinonoz, your question is currently unclear and too broad; leaving it as it is will be unlikely to attract the help you require.

Comment: I made some screenshot, i hope it will help for better understanding. Sorry, it's not easy to explain properly.

Comment: Your screenshots have not improved your question sufficiently, it is still [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: hi Pitinonoz, for "click-actions" I tend to use http://www.sikulix.com (a youtube search will clearify this tool works with screenshot comparison). with that you can click/do everything but you need an active console/session for it to work.